# why large file upload is too slow in https?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, nginx, uwsgi

Facing issue on big file upload in https. Actually the same big file uploading so fast in http for the same domain. 
So my request flows in the below order

AWS ALB(attached ssl) -> Target groups ->ec2 instance -> nginx -> uwsgi -> django

From frontend, am using jquery to upload the file and its in formdata.
eg. 130mb file takes around 12min in https, around 40 seconds in http.

Should I add or change any settings to fix this issue?

My nginx config

[[image: nginx conf]

[image: uwsgi conf]

Comment: I have the same problem with kendo upload file on frontend. Do you have solution for this?